# Is there a way to revert or undo replica set configuration

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset

I have two standalone nodes, which have mongodb running on them. Both of them have a replica set configuration ***rs0*** and start with `rs.initiate()`.
But in some scenarios, I want them to run as individual nodes, but in some cases, I want one to become primary and one to become secondary. But since I have done `rs.initiate()` on both, I won't be able to add any node as secondary.
So is there a way to undo the replica set configuration so that I can enable adding the secondary node.

Comment: Could you explain why you want this setup? Your requirements sound rather weird. Maybe we can find a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Hey @MarkusWMahlberg so along with mongodb I have other services like nginx , vault etc running on these nodes. I wanted to create a setup wherein, they can run in standalone mode or a cluster mode. So I wanted some flexibility in my setup, which will allow it to transition from standalone to cluster mode easily. In the cluster mode, all the services will be running only in the primary node, however only mongodb should be running on secondary node, since data will be replicated from primary to secondary,  if primary goes down, secondary can take over.

Comment: This setup is problematic: a) You should not run anything else than a MongoDB node on a machine. It needs a lot of RAM, and in case you have many concurrent users, the parts will compete for this precious resource. b) Replication is a continuous process utilising the oplog, which is a capped collection. If your changes exceed the oplog, you would be forced to a resync - bad idea if your primary is down. c) What I would do is to do some HA setup for the frontends (on different nodes, maybe adding some dynamically based on load) and have a standard replset as per MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

Switch to local database
Execute the command to make the cllection such as system.replset empty

```
db.system.replset.remove({});
```

Make sure that system.replset in local database is empty by executing the following command:

```
db.system.replset.find();
```

Refernce from : https://vitalflux.com/mongodb-how-to-reset-mongo-replica-set/

Comment: This worked for me, thanks, but first I had to `use local`, and after removal I had to restart the service.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply prepare a new config document and reconfigure the replication.

rs.reconfig(new_config_file)

Comment: Hey @satish doing a reconfig won't help in this scenario, since primary needs to add the secondary using `rs.add` command, but given that secondary too was configured using `rs.initiate` with rs0 it doesn't let me add the secondary node on the primary one. I'm not sure how reconfig on the secondary will work, since I was looking for something that would undo rs.initiate configuration